# Cant save user to the MongoDB Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, backend

So i am trying to save user details to my mongodb database. I was able to successfully save the data prior to hashing the entered password with bcrypt

I am not able to save the userdetails to the database after hashing the password.

Here is my code

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/user");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, Salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, Salt, function (err, hash) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log("Cannot Encrypt");
      }

      var hashedPassword = hash;
      console.log(hashedPassword);

      var newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hashedPassword,
      });

      try {
        const user = newUser.save();
        res.status(200).json({
            status: "user created successfully",
            message: {
                user: user
            }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({
          status: "fail",
          message: error,
        });
      }
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here are the postman screenshots and a screenshot of the VSCode terminal.

[VSCode_terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FVHC.png)

[PostmanAPI_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xVns.png)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is Due to Not using Async/ Await while encrypt a password , but there is a significant way by which you can perform your operations without using `await` with Error Handling by use of `promise`

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/user");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    .then((salt) => {

      //use promise
      bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt)
        .then((hashedPassword) => {
          var newUser = new User({
            username: req.body.username,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword,
          });

          newUser.save()
            .then((user) => {
              res.status(200).json({
                status: "user created successfully",
                message: {
                  user: user,
                },
              });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              res.status(404).json({
                status: "fail",
                message: error,
              });
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          res.status(404).json({
            status: "fail",
            message: error,
          });
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      //handle error incase of failure
      res.status(404).json({
        status: "fail",
        message: error,
      });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have replaced the `await` keyword with `then` and `catch` to handle the promises returned by the asynchronous functions.

Answer (score -1):

The issue seems to be related to the asynchronous nature of the code. The `bcrypt.hash` function is asynchronous and returns a hashed password in the callback function. However, the code is not properly handling the asynchronous behavior, and the `newUser.save()` line is executed before the hashing is completed.

To fix this, you can wrap the code after hashing the password inside a Promise and use `async/await` to properly handle the asynchronous behavior. Here's an updated version of your code:

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/user");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

    var newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });

    const user = await newUser.save();

    res.status(200).json({
      status: "user created successfully",
      message: {
        user: user,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({
      status: "fail",
      message: error,
    });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

In this updated code, the `bcrypt.genSalt` and `bcrypt.hash` functions are awaited to ensure that the hashing is completed before proceeding. The `newUser.save()` line is also awaited to ensure that the user is saved to the database before sending the response.

By using `async/await`, you can write the code in a more synchronous-like style while handling the asynchronous operations correctly.

Comment: Can you please describe in your own words the process you used for creating this answer? Is the answer completely your own original work?

Comment: This appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with this answer, I would encourage you to delete it. **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as it may contain fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. [Posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831), and the moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.